# MongoDB using regex to query array of strings and find the document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of ORDERS which is like:

```
_id:5f8e7d8084378609b2dca93f
user_id:"5f8465a777b1814c588521e2"
price:96
city:"Mumbai City"
totalCost:96

_id:5f8e7d8084378609b2dca93f
user_id:"5f8465a777b1814c588521e2"
price:96
city:"Delhi"
totalCost:96
```

Then in my API I receive data which is in form of array:

```
driverCity = ['Mumbai', 'Ahmednagar', 'Yavatmal', 'Warud', 'Umred']
```

Now how do I query my ORDERS collection and then check that `ORDER.city` is present as a substring is my `driverCity` variable by regex ? it means that if a substring like "mumbai" is present in `ORDER.city` and also in this array I want that result.

Answer (score 2):

If you're querying from the MongoDb driver for Nodejs then you can make a case-insentitive regex query:

```js
const driverCity = ['Mumbai', 'Ahmednagar', 'Yavatmal', 'Warud', 'Umred'];

db.collection("ORDERS").find({
    city: new RegExp(driverCity.map(city => `(${city})`).join('|'),'i')
})
```

**NOTE:** Regex queries in mongodb (or anywhere, really) are a bit heavy and can be slow and resource-intensive. I would recommend your `city` key in the ORDERS collection is indexed.

Comment: and how do i do the other way around?? i mean if driverCity='Mumbai City' and order have city 'Mumbai' just curious :)

Answer (score 1):

Join array element with `|` and make a string, use [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) to get matching city,

```
let driverCity = ['Mumbai', 'Ahmednagar', 'Yavatmal', 'Warud', 'Umred'].join("|");
// "Mumbai|Ahmednagar|Yavatmal|Warud|Umred"

db.collection.find({
  city: {
    $regex: driverCity
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tvGXydEFcVS)

Comment: cool and how do i do the other way around?? i mean if driverCity='Mumbai City' and order have city 'Mumbai'

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/yUv4wUU6G5z here is the link i played with it but seems the other way  isnt working :(